# Requirement tab folder structure

Tags: macros, hp-quality-center

I want to create folder structure in requirement tab and map the test cases  from test plan using QC OTA.I want folder structure same as in the test plan. I am able to download all the test folders path from test plan but I am stuck on creating same folder structure on equipment tab. I did search but could not find any method to create a folder, group and requirement in requirement tab.
Can somebody help me on this .

Answer (score 0):

Have you examined the OTA API Reference which comes with QC? There you find examples like *Finding a unique requirement*, and *Creating a new requirement* with all the example code needed in VB.

Since a folder in the requirements structure is a "normal" requirement which has the type Folder, there is nothing special in creating a folder hierarchy in the requirements-part in QC. Here is some Ruby code to create a folder type requirement in QC:

```
requirementFactory = @tdc.ReqFactory
requirementFolder = requirementFactory.AddItem(ParentReq.ID)
requirementFolder.Name = folder
requirementFolder.TypeId = 'Folder'
requirementFolder.Author = 'Someone'
requirementFolder.Post
```

To create a requirement in this folder, simply use it as parent when creating some other requirement (depending on your configuration of QC, other properties must be set):

```
requirement = requirementFactory.AddItem(requirementFolder.ID)
requirement.Name = name
requirement.Reviewed = 'Not Reviewed'
requirement.TypeId = 'Functional'
requirement.Author = 'Someone'
requirement.Priority = '3-High'
requirement.Post
```